# Fill text color animation while on hover, with animated colors

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to fill the text color of the heading when hovering over it, but the text always changes its color, and I don't know/think that you can have part of a background to one color and the other constantly changing. I have added code with the hover implemented, but without the transition.

```css
:root {
  --txt-color: #fff;
  --txt-box-bg: #424242;
  --main-bg: #000;
  /* front page title text */
  --main-front-color: #00a8ff;
  --second-front-color: #e84118;
  --third-front-color: #fbc531;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* Text */

.head-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}

.main-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono" monospace;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}


/* Allgin */

.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* classes */

.front-page {
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
  color: #000;
  animation: text-rainbow 13s linear infinite;
}

.full-page {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* IDs */

#title-text {
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--main-bg);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--main-front-color);
  animation: stroke-rainbow 13s linear infinite;
}

#title-text:hover {
  color: inherit;
}

@keyframes stroke-rainbow {
  0% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
  25% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: var(--third-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}

@keyframes text-rainbow {
  0% {
    color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
  25% {
    color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page full-page">
  <span id="title-text" class="center head-text">Hi</span>
</div>
```

[What I want](https://codepen.io/m2rt/pen/KwXgaG)

```css
/* REQUIRES FALLBACK FOR FIREFOX */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  align-self: center;
}

a {
  font: 300 42px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 80px;
  color: #d7a150;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #283271, #283271 50%, #d7a150 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: 100%;
}

a:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.23, 1);
  background-position: 0%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you hope to accomplish, is your "What I want" codepen link not what you want?

Comment: Yes, but I am having difficulty actually getting the result I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider a background animation and you can easily achieve this. The idea is to use `background-color` for text coloration then have another background layer that will show/reveal this coloration on hover:

```css
:root {
  --txt-color: #fff;
  --txt-box-bg: #424242;
  --main-bg: #000;
  /* front page title text */
  --main-front-color: #00a8ff;
  --second-front-color: #e84118;
  --third-front-color: #fbc531;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* Text */

.head-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}

.main-text {
  font-family: "IBM Plex Mono" monospace;
  color: var(--txt-color);
}


/* Allgin */

.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* classes */

.front-page {
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
  color: #000;
}

.full-page {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}


/* IDs */

#title-text {
  position: absolute;
  /*Color the text with background*/
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  /**/
  /*The animated layer*/
  background-image:linear-gradient(#000,#000);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  /**/
  transition:1s all;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--main-front-color);
  animation: stroke-rainbow 13s linear infinite,
             text-rainbow 13s linear infinite;
}

#title-text:hover {
  background-size:0% 100%;
}

@keyframes stroke-rainbow {
  0% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
  25% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    border-color: var(--third-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    border-color: var(--second-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    border-color: var(--main-front-color);
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}

@keyframes text-rainbow {
  0% {
    background-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
  25% {
    background-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: var(--third-front-color);
  }
  75% {
    background-color: var(--second-front-color);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: var(--main-front-color);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page full-page">
  <span id="title-text" class="center head-text">Hi</span>
</div>
```